# ie 6 cant find javascript definitions 

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

i have a javascript file a.js ,it content is sometime like this

```
window.model={};

model.init=(
function(){return "something"}
)();
```

in my html files , i have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       model.init();
    });
</script>
```

in chrome , firefox and ie8 it works . but in ie6 or ie7 it will so model is not defined .

i don't know why . could anyone help me .

thanks !

---

i put some alert

in html  :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
           alert("ie6");
       model.init();
    });
</script>
```

in js

```
alert("ie7");
window.model={};

model.init=(
function(){return "something"}
)();
```

it print "ie6" first , but "ie7" never print out

Comment: Im sorry you have to support IE6.......

Comment: [7.1% of the world uses IE6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/), why not give them a beautiful banner telling them their browser sucks and they should upgrade or go away?

Comment: today my user told me than the web not work in his ie brower . so ,i have to fix it

Comment: @John B , i'm in china , the area is red

Answer (score 2):

Reference model the same way you declare it, as a property on `window`.

```
window.model.init=(function(){return "something"})();

$(document).ready(function() {
   window.model.init();
});
```

Or, you could do the opposite and declare it as a global variable.

```
var model={};
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by different execution order, or some "hoisting" problem.

Try initializing  model with "var model = {}". Then try to dump stuff to a log to check the execution order.  IE have tools to use console.log, or you can try firebug lite.